# Observing pinch multi-touch gestures in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, multi-touch, pinch

I am looking to implement a pinch in/out on top of a UITableView,  I have looked at several methods including this one:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects)

But while I can create a `UIViewTouch` object and overlay it onto my UITableView,  scroll events are not being relayed to my UITableView,  I can still select cells, and they respond properly by triggering a transition to a new ViewController object.  But I can not scroll the UITableView despite passing the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded events.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This seems to be a classic problem. In my case I wanted to intercept some events over a UIWebView which can't be subclassed, etc etc.

I've found that the best way to do it is to intercept the events using the UIWindow:

EventInterceptWindow.h

```
@protocol EventInterceptWindowDelegate
- (BOOL)interceptEvent:(UIEvent *)event; // return YES if event handled
@end


@interface EventInterceptWindow : UIWindow {
    // It would appear that using the variable name 'delegate' in any UI Kit
    // subclass is a really bad idea because it can occlude the same name in a
    // superclass and silently break things like autorotation.
    id <EventInterceptWindowDelegate> eventInterceptDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign)
    id <EventInterceptWindowDelegate> eventInterceptDelegate;

@end
```

EventInterceptWindow.m:

```
#import "EventInterceptWindow.h"

@implementation EventInterceptWindow

@synthesize eventInterceptDelegate;

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([eventInterceptDelegate interceptEvent:event] == NO)
        [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Create that class, change the class of your UIWindow in your MainWindow.xib to EventInterceptWindow, then somewhere set the eventInterceptDelegate to a view controller that you want to intercept events.  Example that intercepts a double-tap:

```
- (BOOL)interceptEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *oneTouch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *touchView = [oneTouch view];
    //  NSLog(@"tap count = %d", [oneTouch tapCount]);
    // check for taps on the web view which really end up being dispatched to
    // a scroll view
    if (touchView && [touchView isDescendantOfView:webView]
            && touches && oneTouch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
        if ([oneTouch tapCount] == 2) {
            [self toggleScreenDecorations];
            return YES;
        }
    }   
    return NO;
}
```

Related info here:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/360idev-iphone-developers-conference-presentation

Comment: That method works Great,  and is cleaner than the overlaying objects method.

Thanks!

Comment: Really great solution, was looking for something like this to add gestures to scrollview/tableview, thanks! :)

Comment: Awesome solution.  I've had it running well for a few months now capturing a 3 finger double tap gesture.  Recently one of my more neurotic colleagues was able to cause a crash that appears to be caused by this.  The stack trace shows no objective-c code, however it is throwing a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` on `[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer touchesCancelled:withEvent:] -[UIApplication _cancelTouches:withEvent:sendingTouchesCancelled:includingGestures:]`.  My hypothesis is that the first "3-tap" is starting a PanGesture but then I just kill the event (not gracefully).  Always returning `NO` fixes it.

Comment: Ran out of room above... any thoughts on a graceful cancel would be much appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10403137/779419 for how to use a custom UIWindow when using storyboards.

Answer (score 5):

Nimrod wrote:

> somewhere set the eventInterceptDelegate to a view controller that you want to intercept events

I didn't immediately understand this statement.  For the benefit of anyone else who had the same problem as me, the way I did it was by adding the following code to my UIView subclass which must detect touches.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Register to receive touch events
    MyApplicationAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    EventInterceptWindow *window = (EventInterceptWindow *) appDelegate.window;
    window.eventInterceptDelegate = self;
}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated
{
    // Deregister from receiving touch events
    MyApplicationAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    EventInterceptWindow *window = (EventInterceptWindow *) appDelegate.window;
    window.eventInterceptDelegate = nil;

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


- (BOOL) interceptEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    NSLog(@"interceptEvent is being called...");
    return NO;
}
```

This version of `interceptEvent:` is a simple implementation of pinch-to-zoom detection.  NB. Some code was taken from Beginning iPhone 3 Development by Apress.

```
CGFloat initialDistance;

- (BOOL) interceptEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    // Give up if user wasn't using two fingers
    if([touches count] != 2) return NO;

    UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *) [touches anyObject]).phase;
    CGPoint firstPoint = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint secondPoint = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat deltaX = secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x;
    CGFloat deltaY = secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y;
    CGFloat distance = sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);

    if(phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
    {
        initialDistance = distance;
    }
    else if(phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        CGFloat currentDistance = distance;
        if(initialDistance == 0) initialDistance = currentDistance;
        else if(currentDistance - initialDistance > kMinimumPinchDelta) NSLog(@"Zoom in");
        else if(initialDistance - currentDistance > kMinimumPinchDelta) NSLog(@"Zoom out");
    }
    else if(phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
    {
        initialDistance = 0;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Edit: While this code worked 100% fine in the iPhone simulator, when I ran it on an iPhone device I encountered strange bugs related to the table scrolling.  If this also happens to you, then force the `interceptEvent:` method to return NO in all cases.  This means that the superclass will also process the touch event, but fortunately this did not break my code.

Comment: Why not use `self.view.window` in viewDidAppear?