# Intercepting all touch events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController inside of a navigation based app.  I'd like the view controller to receive all touch events from child objects, such as a tableview and navigation bar.  Or, any other technique that is able to intercept all touch events.

Right now, the following never executes inside of the view controller:

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I need to check a class level flag inside of the touch event, no matter where the touch came from (within any of the view's children).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question for the answer: [Observing pinch multi-touch gestures in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003201/observing-pinch-multi-touch-gestures-in-a-uitableview/2003781#2003781)

Comment: That works well.  I wasn't able to use it the way described in that post.  I added the new class and just check for anything in its  (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event.  I couldn't get it to work by implementing into any other classes, as the post mentions.

Comment: So you set window.eventInterceptDelegate to point to your controller and interceptEvent: wasn't called in your controller? Only the window will get the sendEvent: message from the UIApplication, that's why you have to use delegation to "pass the message on" to some other instance if you need something done there.