# Determining which view touch was in for all touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, touch

I want to determine which view touches occurred in for the entire application, for the purpose of logging touches so that I can go through the logs later and determine what the user did. I know I could subclass UIView and override touchesBegan/Ended to log those, but I am using many instances of UIButton, UISlider, etc in Interface Builder so that wouldn't work unless I also subclassed those classes.

For determining the time since last touch (for an idle screen timeout method) I already have UIApplication subclasses and sendEvent: overridden. The only way I can see to do what I want is to iterate through the main window's subviews, calling touchesForView: on the UIEvent passed into sendEvent:, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to tell which view was touched (whether it's through the sendEvent: method or not). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this will do what you want: [Observing pinch multi-touch gestures in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003201/observing-pinch-multi-touch-gestures-in-a-uitableview/2003781#2003781)

Comment: Well, that wasn't exactly it but you helped with my related question so I'll give you the check.