# Record all touches with timestamp, export touch data to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, export, touches

I am working on a research project that involves user interaction with an iPod. The application runs for approximately 10 hours, and I need to record the following information:

1) How many times was the screen touched?

2) For each touch, where was it touched? (Inside the button vs.outside)

3) What time was it touched? This would preferably be the time of day, but I can do back-calculations if this is not possible.

This information needs to be saved, and exported to a file that can be manipulated in Matlab, Igor, Excel,etc.

The application itself is very simple. A button in the middle of the screen flashes while playing a sound. When a touch event occurs inside the button, the flashing and sound stop for 30 seconds.

My questions is similar to this one from 2010 [How to record all of the user's touches in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924945/how-to-record-all-of-the-users-touches-in-iphone-app). The asker, however, did not provide the details for how he accomplished this, and I'm afraid I need a little more guidance than is given.

I'd be grateful for some advice, or if you could point me to the appropriate resources. I would especially appreciate it if you could also let me know the general area where the code should go. I'm still getting the hang of objective-C.