# Callback Method if user declines Push Notification Prompt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My problem is I want to show a loading screen for the initial Push Notification Prompt "The app wants to send you push notifications."

So if the user hits `yes` I can proceed and start the app in the then invoked delegate methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
  [self hideLoadingScreen];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  [self hideLoadingScreen];
}
```

However if the user hits `no`, none of these methods get called, which makes sense. My question is, is there a different delegate method that gets fired if he declines?

**My problem is if `no` is selected, the loading screens never disappear.** So I somehow need to know when the user is done with the selection.

Comment: in **iOS 10** if you use the `UserNotifications` *framework* then you can find out if the user clicked yes/no using a callback. See [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In iOS 7, when the system's push notification prompt appears, the app becomes inactive and UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification fires. Similarly when the user responds to the prompt (pressing either Yes or No), the app becomes active again and UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification fires.

So you can listen for this notification, and then hide your loading screen.

Note: While the prompt is displayed, the Home button, Notification Center, and Control Center are disabled so they cannot trigger a false-positive UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. However if the user presses Lock button it will trigger UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour is still current in iOS 10

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour is still current in iOS 12

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour is still current in iOS 14 beta 2

Answer (score 6):

You can always get current allowed notification types from:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

Keep in mind user can also disable notification in phone settings.

If you check that on didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken you should see if types you asked for are enabled.

Comment: my problem is that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError never get called if the user hits no on the prompt.

Comment: Upvoted, because despite the fact this doesn't provide a direct answer to the original question it does provide a mention of something quite useful that isn't even mentioned in the documentation of `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`!

Comment: The API for this has changed in the iOS 8 SDK.  On iOS >= 8.0, you have to check `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].categories`.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the answers here are not relevant anymore, or are more complicated than it should be, since UserNotifications framework and iOS 10 you can easily get this data like so:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

// Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) 
{ (granted, error) in
  // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just do the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    BOOL pushEnabled = notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
}
```

This method should be the callback to that push notifications prompt, and from there, you can check the bitmask to see if push notifications were enabled or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it in Swift 3.  They key here is to keep track of the application's lifecycle state internally.  When the push prompt is presented, the application resigns active, but does not enter the background.  This is all in my AppDelegate.swift.

**This is a really big hack and is not recommended in production.  Apple could change the way these alerts are presented and this could break at any time.  This was tested using various iPhones and iPads running iOS 9 and 10.**

```
/// An internal value used to track application lifecycle state
enum ApplicationLifecycleState {
    case willResignActive
    case didEnterBackground
    case willEnterForeground
    case didBecomeActive
    case unknown
}

/// This is used purely for tracking the application lifecycle for handling the system push notification alert
var internalLifecycleState: ApplicationLifecycleState = .unknown {
    didSet {
        // If we're not in the middle of asking for push permissions, none of the below applies, just bail out here
        if !isAskingForPushPermissions { return }

        // WARNING: Application lifecycle trickery ahead
        // The normal application lifecycle calls for backgrounding are as follows:
        // applicationWillResignActive -> applicationDidEnterBackground -> applicationWillEnterForeground -> applicationDidBecomeActive
        // However, when the system push notification alert is presented, the application resigns active, but does not enter the background:
        // applicationWillResignActive -> [user taps on alert] -> applicationDidBecomeActive
        // We can use this discrepancy to our advantage to detect if the user did not allow push permissions

        // If applicationDidBecomeActive
        // AND the previous state was applicationWillResignActive
        // AND the notification types bitmask is 0, we know that the user did not allow push permissions
        // User denied permissions
        if internalLifecycleState == .didBecomeActive
            && oldValue == .willResignActive
            && UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.rawValue == 0 {
            // We're done
            firePushCompletionBlockAndCleanup(registered: false)
        } else {
            // The state below can only be entered on iOS 10 devices.
            // If the user backgrounds the app while the system alert is being shown,
            // when the app is foregrounded the alert will dismiss itself without user interaction.
            // This is the equivalent of the user denying push permissions.
            // On iOS versions below 10, the user cannot background the app while a system alert is being shown.

            if #available(iOS 10, *), internalLifecycleState == .didBecomeActive {
                firePushCompletionBlockAndCleanup(registered: false)
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Used internally to track if the system push notification alert is currently being presented
var isAskingForPushPermissions = false

typealias PushNotificationRegistrationCompletionBlock = ((_ registered: Bool) -> Void)

// ...

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {    
    internalLifecycleState = .willResignActive
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    internalLifecycleState = .didEnterBackground
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    internalLifecycleState = .willEnterForeground
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    internalLifecycleState = .didBecomeActive
}

// ...

func setupPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication = UIApplication.shared, completion: @escaping PushNotificationRegistrationCompletionBlock) {
    isAskingForPushPermissions = true
    pushCompletionBlock = completion
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound, .badge], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

fileprivate func firePushCompletionBlockAndCleanup(registered: Bool) {
    pushCompletionBlock?(registered)
    pushCompletionBlock = nil
    isAskingForPushPermissions = false
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    // application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken may be called more than once (once for each notification type)
    // By checking that the notification types bitmask is greater than 0, we can find the final time this is called (after the user actually tapped "allow")
    // If the user denied push permissions, this function is never called with a positive notification type bitmask value
    if UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.rawValue ?? 0 > 0 {
        firePushCompletionBlockAndCleanup(registered: true)
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register for notifications with error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    firePushCompletionBlockAndCleanup(registered: false)
}
```

Usage:

```
appDelegate.setupPushNotifications(completion: { [weak self] (registered) in
    // If registered is false, the user denied permissions
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3** and **Swift 4.0** 
Using NotificationCenter and the AppDelegate method `didRegister notificationSettings`. NotificationSettings show whether the users opted for badges, sounds, etc. and will be an empty array if they declined push notifications.  It is fired specifically when users respond to the push notifications prompt and seems to be what most devs use, since it's more specific than checking didBecomeActive.  But Apple might change this.  Who knows?

Unfortunately, NotificationCenter does not have a preset notification name so you either have to setup and extension (see end) or use the raw value in (SO has more on this).

In AppDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
      // if not registered users will have an empty set of settings
      let accepted: Bool = !notificationSettings.types.isEmpty
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "didRespondToPrompt"), object: self, userInfo: ["didAccept" : accepted])
}
```

Then observe wherever you need to, for example in a view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Lifecycle
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.didRespondToPushPrompt(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "didRespondToPrompt"), object: nil)

   }
    @objc func didRespondToPushPrompt(_ notification: Notification) {

       if let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = notification.userInfo, let didAccept: Bool = userInfo[NSNotificationKeyNames.didAccept] as? Bool, !didAccept {
        //if user doesn't accept, do this...

       } else  {
       //all other situations code goes here
      }

   }
}
```

Couple of things: First, for Swift 4.0, I'm using "@objc" in front of one method, but it's not necessary for Swift 3.
Also, for using NotificationCenter, in practice I did not use "rawValue".  Instead I made an extension like so:

```
import Foundation

extension NSNotification.Name {
   static let DidRegisterForPushNotifications = NSNotification.Name("DidRegisterForPushNotifications")
}
```

Which I could then use like so:

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.DidRegisterForPushNotifications, object: self, userInfo: ["didAccept" : myBool])`
etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

**2nd May 2019**

This is the implementation to check if notifications are authorized any time in your app, Simple call this function.

```
    private func checkNotificationsAuthorizationStatus() {
    let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    userNotificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (notificationSettings) in
        switch notificationSettings.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("The app is authorized to schedule or receive notifications.")
        case .denied:
            print("The app isn't authorized to schedule or receive notifications.")

        case .notDetermined:
            print("The user hasn't yet made a choice about whether the app is allowed to schedule notifications.")
        case .provisional:
            print("The application is provisionally authorized to post noninterruptive user notifications.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have a BOOL variable to check it in your AppDelegate because there seems to be no way other than using external APIs. See [this](http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/icenium-everlive/what-if-user-declines-push-notifications).

```
AppDelegate.m

// declare a BOOL 
BOOL allow = NO;

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
allow = YES;
  [self hideLoadingScreen];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  allow = YES;
  [self hiedLoadingScreen];
}
```

Now I guess you can access this BOOL variable to differentiate when Don't allow is pressed or not.

Comment: hmm but when to access the BOOL? there seems to be no callback fired if the user doesnt allow Push Notifications.

Comment: You want to disappear the loading screen right? If I am guessing right then you show the user a loading screen at the launch. Then app asks for allowing pushnotification. If allowed then show a different screen, if disallowed then show different screen. Right?

Comment: well, it´s the same screen on allow and disallow, but basically you are right. as soon as the user presses yes or no, the current loading screen should disappear.

Comment: One way I can think of is using NSTimer but that wont be user friendly. Another way that may work is intercepting every touch in UIWindow. Here this may help youhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003201/observing-pinch-multi-touch-gestures-in-a-uitableview/2003781#2003781

Comment: so you have the same impression as me, that there are no callbacks fired if the user declines push notifications?

Comment: Yes that seems true. That Alert View is generated by ios system, independent of the app and I dont think Apple has provided any APIs to access it.

Comment: that´s awful. Luckily we agreed on not showing a loading screen while the pop up appears now.

Comment: Good for you. Enjoy your day!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **SWIFT 2** code example for you guys ... It's complicated little bit ,but I hope my comments will help you understand it.

**Define variables**

```
var appDidBecomeActiveCount = 0
var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults!
```

**AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if userDefaults.valueForKey("FirstLaunche") == nil {
            userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunche")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }

        // Register for notification
        //iOS 8+
        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert , UIUserNotificationType.Badge ,UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

**AppDelegate - applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
            //Delay until alert get dismissed and notification type setted in app
            delay(0.5, closure: { () -> () in
                self.checkTheDilemma()
            })
}
//I love this short method <3_<3
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

**Check action**

```
func checkTheDilemma (){
        //Checking if this user turned off push notifications or didn't allow it at all
        let notificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types

        if userDefaults.valueForKey("FirstLaunche") as! Bool == true {
            //User now is asked for notification permission because it's app's first launche
            // if appDidBecomeActiveCount == 0 --> Pop up message will appeare
            // if appDidBecomeActiveCount == 1 --> Pop up message dismissed
            // if notificationType?.rawValue == 0 --> Notifications off
            // if notificationType?.rawValue > 0  --> Notifications on
            if notificationType?.rawValue == 0
                && appDidBecomeActiveCount == 1 { //If user disabled notifications from pop up alert
                    // ** User just tapped "Don't allow" btn :\
                    // Do what ever you are here for

                    //Now set FirstLaunche = false
                    userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "FirstLaunche")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
            }
        } else {
            if notificationType?.rawValue == 0
                && appDidBecomeActiveCount == 0 { // This guy is not registered for push notification
                    // ** User disabled notifications in past (because this is not his first launch)
            }
        }
        appDidBecomeActiveCount++
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if user has cancelled the notification prompt in `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` method that fires after calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` by checking the `notificationSettings.types`.

If you have requested a number of settings but `notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone` means, that user has cancelled the prompt.

But don't forget that `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method is now deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

A great way using C# Xamarin as of iOS 13

I put it in a timer on the page where I prompt and check the authorization status

It may be possible to get the actual callback but this way works for me

```
using System.Timers;

Timer notificationsPermissionTimer = new Timer();

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  SetupNotificationsPermissionTimer();
  base.ViewDidLoad();
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
  this.notificationsPermissionTimer.Elapsed -= NotificationsPermissionTimer_Elapsed;
  base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
}
private void SetUpNotificationsPermissionTimer()
{
  this.notificationsPermissionTimer = new Timer();
  this.notificationsPermissionTimer.Interval = 500;
  this.notificationsPermissionTimer.Start();
  this.notificationsPermissionTimer.Elapsed += NotificationsPermissionTimer_Elapsed;
}

private void NotificationsPermissionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  Task.Run(CheckNotificationsAuthorizationStatus);
}

private async Task CheckNotificationsAuthorizationStatus()
{
  var userNotificationCenter = await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettingsAsync();
  switch(userNotificationCenter.AuthorizationStatus)
  {
    case UNAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:
      // Do Something
      break;
    case UNAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
      // Do Something
      break;
    case UNAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
      // Do Nothing
      break;
    case UNAuthorizationStatus.Provisional:
      break;
  }
}
```