# What is the Callback Method if You Click "Don't Allow" in Push Notification Popup?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

There's a push notification popup that appears on fresh install of app. There are two choices, OK and Don't Allow (if i remember it correctly.)

I want to know what's the call back method if I click "Don't Allow". The thing is, I implemented  didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications because I thought that if I click "Don't Allow" it would go straight to that method in AppDelegate. However, the method wasn't called.

My problem is I need to know the event when user clicks on "Don't Allow". Is there a way to do this? 
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications is when communication with apple registration service fail, there is no way to know a user just clicked on don't allow, but you can check UIApplication, there is a method to know the state of PushNotification registration

Comment: Did you find a work around? I posted anther question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934729/how-do-i-know-if-user-didnt-allow-push-notifications

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is no delegate callback however from here:[Callback Method if user declines Push Notification Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053092/callback-method-if-user-declines-push-notification-prompt)

You can have a BOOL variable to check it in your AppDelegate,

```
AppDelegate.m

// declare a BOOL 
BOOL allow = NO;

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
  allow = YES;
  [self doWhatever];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  allow = YES;
  [self doWhatever];
}
```

Comment: I see. so there's no way to solve my problem then. thank you so much for all the replies.

Comment: pasting code from another question isn't an answer

Comment: @JeromeDiaz no need to get upset Jerome, I referenced the original/

Answer (score -3):

```
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications
```

is when communication with apple registration service fail, there is no way to know a user just clicked on don't allow, but you can check UIApplication, there is a method to know the state of PushNotification registration

```
NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]; 
if (rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNote) {
    // application is not registered for any type of push notification
}
```

Comment: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications is not called when a user clicks no.

Comment: read my text, I already said it it wasn't called, I even told it in the comment below the question before you even put your own answer