# How do I know if user didn't allow push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704501/what-is-the-callback-method-if-you-click-dont-allow-in-push-notification-popu) but didn't understand if there is a clear answer.

I can tell if the user pressed "don't allow" on the SECOND launch of the app by setting a flag:

```
BOOL didRequest = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DidRequestPushNotifications"];
    UIRemoteNotificationType types =    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone && didRequest)
    {
        [self showAlertToUserToEnableRemoteNotificationsOnDeviceInSettings];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidRequestPushNotifications"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

But for the first launch of the app - both delegate methods for success and failure aren't called and that means that there is no way to know for sure.

Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer you have linked, a work around I can think of is, once user successfully registered for pushes, You can store the device token in the `NSUserDefaults`.

This way you can check if the value of that user setting is `nil` or not.