# registerForRemoteNotificationTypes does not work only with iOS7 installed iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, push-notification

Every thing is OK with my production/development certificates and provisionProfiles. And below code is successfully being called  `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` with iOS6 system installed devices

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // my implementations

    return YES;
}
```

But when I debugged with iOS7 installed devices, neither `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` are getting called. I distributed app for testers using `Ad-hoc` distribution and the same problem with iOS7 devices.

What may be cause connected with my problem?

P.S. My `XCode` version: 5.1 (5B130a)

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, but only when the user has selected do not allow push notifications from the prompt. 

In this scenario neither of those delegates are being called. Both while the prompt is being displayed and all subsequent calls. 

I have investigated using enabledRemoteNotificationTypes (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23280876/344393) but this value is UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone prior to the user being prompted and also after they have selected do not allow. It would have been nice of apple to provide a UIRemoteNotificationTypeNotSelected (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

its working for me
hope help you

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

return YES;
}   







 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"%@",deviceToken);

}
```

Comment: That is very strange in my situation. I don't know why my problem only with iOS 7 devices

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ad-Hoc provisioning profile and make sure push notifications is enabled