# Can we have control of "Allow Push Notifications” dialog ios for push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In my application, depending on user selection of allow or don't allow option in push notification system dialog("Allow Push Notification" dialog), want to perform two different tasks. Can I get some help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053092/callback-method-if-user-declines-push-notification-prompt

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationDelegate` comes with

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

method which is C
called to tell the delegate the types of local and remote notifications that can be used to get the user’s attention. You can implement the above method, as it will be called when user presses Allow or Don't allow.