# Wait for push notification response before segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that requests from the user push notifications. This is shown on a separate view controller with a bit of extra information explaining why we need to enable PN.

There is a segue set up to push to the next view however I would like to perform the segue only after the user has selected don't allow or OK on the popup.

I have tried using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NotificationViewController.notificationsSet), name: "pushNotificationMessage", object: nil)
```

and

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0 ..< deviceToken.length
    {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(NSNotification(name: "pushNotificationMessage", object: nil))
}
```

but this sends the notification immediately after the view is loaded.

Is there a way to pause on a view until the user responds to the message?

Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053092/callback-method-if-user-declines-push-notification-prompt) should help you

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you