# Can iOS device receive data payload if notifications are disabled?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I wonder if there is a possibility to handle data payload somehow when the user has disabled notifications and app is in foreground. In such case APN returns success (notification is sent), but `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never invoked.

When the user disables notifications I do not expect him to get any notification in the tray. However, I am looking for a way how to receive the data payload in the app delegate. For example, if user disables notifications in Android system tray message is never shown, however, notification handler is invoked and the app receives the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user denies permission for receiving remote notifications, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will never be called. I believe the best option would be to convince the user to allow remote notifications.

Below links might help you:

[User Decline Push Notification CallBack Methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053092/callback-method-if-user-declines-push-notification-prompt)

[Right way to ask users for permission.](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/)